# Minimally disruptive method for capturing automatic migrations in an explicit migration?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I'm in a bit of a pickle. I've inherited a project using EF, where:

- Automatic migrations were initially turned on
- Some automatic migrations were added
- Some explicit migrations were added
- Automatic migrations were then turned off

Nothing is broken, as the machines where this code is deployed have moved in parallel with the dev machines and consequently they all have full working DBs.

My concern is that if we ever deployed to another machine, only the explicit migrations would be applied. In fact, I've found that this is true when trying to run the project on a fresh dev machine.

Now, I've been able to cajole the thing into running by generating SQL creation scripts and running these on the new machine. Clearly this isn't a long term solution.

One option I can see is to clear out all the migrations and migration history (in the `__MigrationHistory`) table and create a single new "initial" migration, which would cover everything. My concern with this is that I'd have to perform this surgery on every machine running the code - including production servers.

Is there any way to retrospectively capture the initial automatic migrations into a new explicit migration, that is only run in entirely fresh environments?

Comment: If everything is in sync, reset the migrations as you have suggested. Establish a new baseline (`add-migration NewBaseline -IgnoreChanges`) and then track migrations moving forward. We have done this several times to clean things up.

Answer (score 0):

If you have ability to update your database manually, one option you have is to run `Update-Database -Script`. Then you'll be able to see each of the Migrations (even the automatic ones) and the SQL commands as they will be applied in order. 
Go ahead and save that entire SQL file, because you'll need it for the next steps.

Next, look through each of the blocks of commands which will be separated by an `INSERT` command containing a huge Base64 string. You'll see that each of the migration's steps are split up and put in order, including the automatic migrations. For each of these pairs we really just need everything above the `INSERT` command and below the `INSERT` command of the last migration. I'll call these the migration operations.

Granted, I realize that this will take some time at scale, but next run `Add-Migration -IgnoreChanges` to scaffold an empty migration then in the `Up()` method add a new `Sql()` operation and copy the current migration operations into it (i.e. `Sql("<your_awesome_script>")`). You may need to make a corresponding `Down()` as well to be safe.

Next, go back and look at the TimeStamps of the migrations immediately before and after the automatic one you're working with. This will be in the `INSERT` command as the first parameter like, `201710152132114_<MigrationName>`. Pick a DateTime in between those two and then name your new migration's `.cs` file using that DateTime. This will order the migration correctly inside of your solution for future use.

Finally, open up the migration's `.Designer.cs` file and inside of the the `ImigrationMetadata.Id` on the `get` replace the existing `Id` string the new Migration name you've created. This is what EF will use programatically to order your migration operations.

If moving to a new machine that already has some migrations applied, try looking at the instance of the database it's using and see what the Id of the latest entry in the `__MigrationHistory` table is. Then in your development environment Revert your migrations targetting *that* migration and follow the steps listed above for each automatic. If you can convert all of your automatic migrations like this one time, you'll be able to deploy to new environments will all explicit migrations in the future.

I would definitely suggest not trying this on a production machine until it has worked for you in development and in a test environment.

Comment: Thanks for this. I've not tried it yet, but I can see how it would work. I'm not sure this would class as "minimally disruptive", but if it's the _least_ disruptive way, then it'll have to do.